# wordpress navigation bar in mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress

I`m using a bootstrap theme for my wordpress site. Here is the navigation bar code from header.php.

```
<?php
        // Collapsed navbar menu toggle
           global $xsbf_theme_options;
           $navbar = '<div class="navbar '.$xsbf_theme_options['navbar_classes'] . '">'
        .'<div class="container">'
        .'<div class="navbar-header">'
        .'<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">'
        .'<span class="icon-bar"></span>'
        .'<span class="icon-bar"></span>'
        .'<span class="icon-bar"></span>'
        .'</button>';

    // Site title (Bootstrap "brand") in navbar. Hidden by default. Customizer will
    // display it if user turns of the main site title and tagline.
    $navbar .= '<a class="navbar-brand" href="'
        .esc_url( home_url( '/' ) )
        .'" rel="home">'
        .get_bloginfo( 'name' )
        .'</a>';

    $navbar .= '</div><!-- navbar-header -->';

    // Display the desktop navbar
    $navbar .= wp_nav_menu( 
        array(  'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'container_class' => 'navbar-collapse collapse', //<nav> or <div> class
        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', //<ul> class
        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker(),
        'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
        'echo'  => false
        ) 
    );
    echo apply_filters( 'xsbf_navbar', $navbar );
    ?>

    </div><!-- .container -->
    </div><!-- .navbar -->
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

So far so good. My navigation child css:

```
    .navbar {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #222;
    width: 70%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-nav >ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar-brand {
    display: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #978476;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #605F65;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #605F65;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    background-color: #E7E4E4;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

My problem is that i can't change the navigation background when in mobile view. How can i do that? It remain transparent because of the:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
        background-color: #E7E4E4;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have two background colours? Just remove the one you don't need within a media query.

Comment: My background-color for the entire nav is #222, but when in mobile i want it #E7E4E4

Comment: thats confusing Edy, .navbar background is #222 and you want it #e3e4e4 but as you stated `It remain transparent`.. does this mean that the #222 background didn't applied too? focus on .navbar because there is where #222 comes from.. not in the `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Write a media query which target mobile phones on bottom of css file and put background color.

Since bootstrap uses mobile first aproach, set that color as default, then for larger devices put transparent.

Answer (score 0):

This is the media query I was referring to.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar {
        background-color: #e7e4e4;
    }
}
```

Make sure you call your custom styles after the Bootstrap stylesheet.

Comment: This one clrealy set the background color to #e7e4e4 but maybe i wasnt clear enough. I want the toggle menu with links to become #e7e4e4. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Then just remove the transparent as you don't need to have two colours targeting one selector.

Comment: If i'l remove the transparent attribute the <ul> will have #e7e4e4 and the rest of the navbar #222.